# mongodb dropping the collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I save this collection with marioChar but I found that I should write it with small letter not in camel case and if i write it with camel case I found error

```
 beforeEach(function(done){
        mongoose.connection.collections.mariochars.drop(function(){
          `enter code here`done();
    });
    });
```

is that should to write it with small letter or what ?

Comment: No idea what you are asking. You are using the `connection.collections` accessor which is directly using the underlying driver. So you need to use it's methods and the real collection name.

Comment: the real collection name is "marioChar" but if i put it as is  it going to be err but if i put it "mariochar" with small letters it work .... have you got me